# Checkerboard transition with CSS3 Only?

Tags: animation, css, transition

Is it possible to create a checkerboard type of transition with CSS 3 Only?

Comment: I don't believe so. Have you seen something similar that you can link to?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it with images (can't see how this would work with anything else), you could use a number of divs in a grid, all with the same background image, but with different background position so that it just looks like a normal image. You could then have another image behind that one by absolutely positioning them both. You could then animate the opacity of each of the divs on the grid with different delays to get the checkerboard effect.

By using nth-child selectors you could change the delays for every other one, or something more complex.

You'd likely want JS to then set the background image of the divs to the image behind them, and then remove the transition and set opacity to 1. You could then change the image behind to something new to checkerboard to that one.

If you make this, please let me know – it sounds awesome!

Comment: That is a great idea. It seems like this is the only way. I wish I could power the checkerboard transition with an animated CSS3 mask... something which may not exist. Having a background image repeated so many times makes me worry about bogging down the browser. Is that a legitimate concern? Or... I could trigger hardware acceleration like shown here??? http://24ways.org/2010/intro-to-css-3d-transforms ... so much new stuff to learn.

Comment: I think you'll just have to try it! Using canvas might be another avenue to explore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is 'transition' in your message. But you can draw a checkerboard with only css3. Look at this : http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/